# brew update fails wtih fatal: could not read Username

Tags: terminal, homebrew, software-update

```
$ brew update
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Error: homebrew/homebrew-dupes does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes` to remove it.
homebrew/homebrew-versions does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-versions` to remove it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to fix the gitconfig in my local I found out that actually brew was the issue.

For me **homebrew-dupes** and **homebrew-versions** caused the problem. But the fix is similar to taps.

Just do

```
brew tap
```

which gives you

```
...
homebrew/dupes
homebrew/versions
...
```

a simple untap

```
brew untap homebrew/dupes
brew untap homebrew/versions
```

after which everything is ok

```
brew update
Already up-to-date.
```